# How do you list out all output / generate files from a Gradle Build?

Tags: github, gradle, build, build.gradle, release

Currently I am using the following to generate list of output files which I want for another plugin which does Github releases.

```
[
        "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar",
        "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}-javadoc.jar",
        "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}-sources.jar"
]
```

I am not very satisfied with this as I am manually specifying each type of file (doc, source, class). I am looking to make this more generic where I can reuse without any modification for any project which might have more or less outputs and also may not be in the default location and some outputs may not even be Java outputs. I.e. changing output location, the tasks to run or plugging elsewhere in the script should not break this part of the script and should be reusable without editing. **The question is how do you get a list of all the outputs as a List of String like above.**

More detailed code snippet:

...

```
plugins {
    id 'co.riiid.gradle' version '0.4.2'
}
```

...

```
ext {
    org = 'MicroTrader'
    repo = org + '/' + project.name
    releaseNotesFile = 'RELEASE_NOTES.md'
    host = 'github.com'
    hostUrl = 'https://' + host + '/'
    orgUrl = hostUrl + org
    websiteUrl = hostUrl + repo
    vcsUrl = websiteUrl + '.git'
    scmUrl = 'scm:git@' + host + ':' + repo + '.git'
    issueTrackerUrl = websiteUrl + '/issues'
    ossrhUsername = ((project.hasProperty('ossrhUsername') ? ossrhUsername : System.getenv('OSSRH_USER')) ?: System.getProperty('ossrh.user')) ?: ' '
    ossrhPassword = ((project.hasProperty('ossrhPassword') ? ossrhPassword : System.getenv('OSSRH_PASSWORD')) ?: System.getProperty('ossrh.password')) ?: ' '
    bintray_user = ((project.hasProperty('bintray_user') ? bintray_user : System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')) ?: System.getProperty('bintray.user')) ?: ' '
    bintray_api_key = ((project.hasProperty('bintray_api_key') ? bintray_api_key : System.getenv('BINTRAY_KEY')) ?: System.getProperty('bintray.apikey')) ?: ' '
    artifactory_user = ((project.hasProperty('artifactory_user') ? artifactory_user : System.getenv('ARTIFACTORY_USER')) ?: System.getProperty('artifactory.user')) ?: ' '
    artifactory_password = ((project.hasProperty('artifactory_password') ? artifactory_password : System.getenv('ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD')) ?: System.getProperty('artifactory.password')) ?: ' '
    github_api_key = ((project.hasProperty('github_api_key') ? github_api_key : System.getenv('GITHUB_KEY')) ?: System.getProperty('github.apikey')) ?: ' '
}
```

...

```
github {
    owner = project.org
    repo = project.name
    token = project.github_api_key
    tagName = project.version
    targetCommitish = 'master'
    name = 'v' + project.version
    body = Files.exists(Paths.get('' + projectDir + '/' + releaseNotesFile)) ?
            new File('' + projectDir + '/' + releaseNotesFile).text :
            (Files.exists(Paths.get('' + baseDir + '/' + releaseNotesFile)) ?
                    new File('' + baseDir + '/' + releaseNotesFile).text : '')
    assets = [
            "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar",
            "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}-javadoc.jar",
            "${buildDir}/libs/${project.name}-${project.version}-sources.jar"
    ]
}
```

...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reading the `outputs` property on all of the tasks in your build used to generate the artifacts:

`project(':my-sub-project').jar.outputs`

Another option is to use the `archives` configuration from all of your sub-projects:

`project(':my-sub-project').configurations.archives.allArtifacts`

Comment: How do you do this if you do not have sub projects. It is the main / root project I am interested in.

Comment: Just use `<task>.outputs` that will implicitly reference the current project instance (.i.e. `project.<task>.outputs`). `<task>` is the actual task name, or you can also use `tasks.<task name>`.

Comment: Great! Maybe you can add this also to the answer.